# Next.js build in Dockerfile failing because of missing .next/cache folder

Tags: docker, next.js

I'm experiencing an strange situation where the same Dockerfile and CodeBuild project config is failing prod but not in dev.

```bash
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:14-alpine AS deps
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --production=false --pure-lockfile --ignore-engines

FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:14-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat curl
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/package.json .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules

RUN DEBUG=graphql:errors,graphql:queries,cache:redis DEBUG_COLORS=true npm run build --debug

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 app_user \
  && adduser --system --uid 1001 --shell /bin/bash -D app_user \
  && chown -R app_user:app_user /app \
  && echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/curl" >> /etc/profile

USER app_user
HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=5s --retries=3 CMD curl -f http://localhost:8080/blog || exit 1
EXPOSE 8080 6379
ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "start"]
```

I'm getting the error: `[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/.next/cache']`

In detail this is the error output:

```bash
Build error occurred
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/.next/cache'] {
   errno: -2,
   code: 'ENOENT',
   syscall: 'stat',
   path: '/app/.next/cache'
 }
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

I've thought about permissions issue, but by the time build command runs, `root` user is still in action.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if a directory isn't present, Docker doesn't create it automatically. So you need to create it and give `app_user` write permission to it.

```
# COPY commands
RUN mkdir -p .next/cache && chown -R app_user .next/cache && chmod -R 644 .next/cache
# Debug command
```

Comment: By the time build command runs, `root` user is acting

Comment: You're changing the ownership of the directory, so it shouldn't be an issue.